# Trigger running every time despite conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to write an update trigger on a table which would cause it to run an additional update statement only if a certain column has been changed, so far the trigger runs the update no matter what, hoping maybe someone can see what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StatusChangedUpdateTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[Trans_Order] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
    DECLARE @OldOrderStatusId INT, @NewStatusOrderId INT, @ERRNUM INT;

BEGIN
    SET @OldOrderStatusId = (SELECT OrderStatusId FROM deleted);
    SET @NewStatusOrderId = (SELECT OrderStatusId FROM inserted);

    IF (@OldOrderStatusId != @NewStatusOrderId)
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Trans_Order
    SET StatusChanged = 1
    WHERE Id = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
END
```

For some reason this is running no matter what, I can never set `StatusChanged` to 0 as it will automatically flip it back to 1 even if the `OrderStatusId` hasn't changed. So my update statement is running no matter what, so I am guessing I am doing something wrong in the if statement.

Comment: Your trigger is flawed; it assumes an `UPDATE` only ever effects 1 row. That is simply not true.

Comment: Also - your `IF` isn't followed by a `BEGIN` - so it's really **only** for the one statement following it - the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` - the `UPDATE` will **always** be executed - even if your determination of the two Id's returns that they are equal ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . Your logic seems strange.  I would expect:

```
UPDATE t
    SET StatusChanged = 1
FROM Trans_Order t JOIN
     Inserted i
     ON t.id = i.id JOIN
     Deleted d
     ON t.id = d.id
WHERE i.OrderStatusId <> d.OrderStatusId;
```

You might need to take `NULL` values into account -- although your code does not.

Note that your code is just a bug waiting to happen, because it assumes that `inserted` and `deleted` have only one row.

The specific problem with your code is that it is really:

```
IF (@OldOrderStatusId != @NewStatusOrderId)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END;
UPDATE Trans_Order
SET StatusChanged = 1
WHERE Id = (SELECT ID FROM inserted);
```

Your indentation has confused the logic.  However, you should still use the set-based version so the trigger does not fail.

Comment: Trans_Order and inserted will have identical values for the updated rows - so the join to inserted is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to approach your trigger is as follows:

```
create or alter trigger [dbo].[StatusChangedUpdateTrigger] on [dbo].[Trans_Order] 
after update 
as
set nocount on
if @@RowCount=0 return

if Update(OrderStatusId)
begin
    update t
    set statusChanged=1
    from inserted i join deleted d on d.id=i.id and d.OrderStatusId != i.OrderStatusId 
    join Trans_Order t on t.id=i.id
end
```

Always test `@@rowcount` and return if no rows updated.
Always put `set` options before `DML`

As you are only looking to update if a specific column is updated you can test specifically for that and if the update statement that's run doesn't touch that column the trigger will not run.

This will correctly account for multiple rows being updated and only update those where the new value is different to the old value.